# Change style from javascript

Tags: javascript, svg

I have a problem integrating javascript "percentage" output in css..

I am new to javascript and i just can't get this to work...

```js
var number = 65;
var total = 170;
var percentage = (number / total * 100).toFixed(2);
document.getElementById("svgcircle").style.strokeDasharray = percentage;
```

```css
#svgcircle {
  stroke-width: 5px;
  stroke: red;
  stroke-dasharray: 80, 100;
  stroke-linecap: round;
}
```

```html
<svg id='svgcircle' height="50" width="50">
        <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="16"/>
    </svg>
```

Comment: [You appear to be successfully changing the value](https://i.imgur.com/7cKHEtR.png) but [doesn't work](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/) is a poor description of the problem. What did you expect to happen? How is that different from what is actually happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`stroke-dasharray` takes 2 arguments
`<dash-length>, <gap-length>`

if you want a percentage output just put 100 to `gap-length`

```js
var number = 65;
var total = 170;
var percentage = ((number / total) * 100).toFixed(2);

document.getElementById("svgcircle").style.strokeDasharray = percentage+', '+100; // <<<< add gap-length here
```

```css
#svgcircle {
    stroke-width: 5px;
    stroke: red;
    stroke-dasharray: 80,100;
    stroke-linecap: round;
 }
```

```html
<svg id='svgcircle' height="50" width="50">
    <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="16"/>
</svg>
```